# For some reason I keep getting the error: Array bounds cannot appear in type specifiers and i am not sure what this means

Tags: vb.net

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient



Public Class Form2
Private conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=wal1sql1;Initial Catalog=ValueTracker;Integrated Security=True")
Private da As SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl ValueSources", cs) 
Private ds As DataSet


'Declaration
Public Property AllowDBNull As Boolean


Private Sub AddNullAllowedColumn()
    Dim column As DataColumn
    column = New DataColumn("ValueSourceID", _
        System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    column.AllowDBNull = True

    ' Add the column to a new DataTable. 
    Dim table As DataTable
    table = New DataTable
    table.Columns.Add(column)
End Sub


Private Sub ValueSourcesBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ValueSourcesBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.ValueTrackerDataSet)

    Me.ValueSourcesBindingSource.EndEdit()


End Sub
```

I got the error at `Private da As SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl ValueSources", cs)`

Comment: the new keyword is missing:
Private da As new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl ValueSources", cs)

Answer (score 1):

Your missing `New` in your line. When you write `Private da As SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl ValueSources", cs)` it thinks that the arguments you gave are part of the type declaration. 
Use this instead,

```
Private da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl ValueSources", cs)
```

This will call the constructor and should fix your error.